# AWS CloudFormation - Share user-data script using cfn-init across EC2s

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, user-data

I have an instance resource like such:

```
testservice:
  Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
  Metadata:
    AWS::CloudFormation::Init:
      configSets:
        serviceConfigSet:
          - serviceConfig
      serviceConfig:
        packages:
          yum:
            salt-minion: []
        commands:
          hostnameConfig:
            command: hostname test-service-1.0
        services:
          sysvinit:
            salt-minion:
              enabled: 'true'
              ensureRunning: 'true'
  Properties:
    ImageId: !Ref BaseServiceAmi
    KeyName: test_ssh_key
    SubnetId: !Ref ServiceSubnetId
    UserData:
      'Fn::Base64':
        'Fn::Sub': |
          #!/bin/bash

          yum update -y

          yum install -y aws-cfn-bootstrap

          /opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource testservice --configsets serviceConfigSet --region ${AWS::Region}
```

However, I want to move the `UserData` script into a parameter and reuse it across multiple Instance resources. This should be trivial, but I can't find a way to get the current resource's name inside the user data script (I've explicitly set it in this part:  `--resource testservice`).

Is there a way I can get the resource name via reference from inside the user data script so I can generalize it? It doesn't appear in the pseudo-parameter list.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best option would be to use nested stacks. If you can convert all the settings in your 'AWS::EC2::Instance' resource to parameters, you can create a template stack for that resource and call it from another template.

Quick Info:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/best-practices.html#stackpolicy

How to use:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-stack.html